# Moving sprites in sine wave

Tags: c, math, trigonometry

can someone slap me an idea or math formula on how to make my enemies move in a sine wave

tried something like this but they just move at the same time so they just create a straight line of enemies moving left and right.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  float y = sinf( 100+delta_time*0.06f) * 75;
  float x = game->enemy[i].base_x + y;
  game->enemy[i].x = x  ;  
  game->enemy[i].y += 1; 
  SDL_Rect rect = { game->enemy[i].x ,   game->enemy[i].y   ,game->enemy[i].w, game->enemy[i].h};
  SDL_RenderCopy(game->renderer , game->enemy[i].sprite , NULL , &rect);
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you intend exactly, but if you want all sprites to move on the same sine wave, your sine argument shouldn't depend on time, which is the same for all sprites, but on the sprites'  _x_ positions.

Comment: I am trying to achieve something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ol9TsSs-9ok&feature=youtu.be&t=1m38s

Answer (score 0):

Let `v=(v_x,v_y)` be the overall direction of the enemy.  Let `o` be the vector `o=(-v_y/||v||,v_x/||v||)` where `||v||=sqrt(v_x.v_x+v_y.v_y)` is the norm of `v`. The vector `o` is perpendicular to `v`. A sinusoidal motion is wanted in that direction. Consequently, the position `p(t)=(x(t),y(t))` is defined as :

```
x(t)=v_x.t-A.v_y/||v||.sin(w.t)
y(t)=v_y.t+A.v_x/||v||.sin(w.t)
```

where `A` is the magnitude of the ossilations and `w` the pulsation of the ossilations. The corresponding frequency is `f=w/(2pi)`.Then, the wavelength `lambda=||v||/f` corresponds to the length of ossilations.

If the enemy is moving in the x direction (`v_y=0`) then :

```
x(t)=v_x.t
y(t)=A.sin(w.t)
```

The length of ossilations is `lambda=2pi.v_x/w`.